# How do I get the list item ID of an item I just created in a Visual Webpart

Tags: development, visual-web-part

I have a visual webpart which creates a list item, but I need to reference the newly created item's ID for later use in the same webpart. How would I do this in C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The value of the ID is invalid after Add() and but instead created during Update(). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.id%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Example:

```
SPList itemList = web.Lists["Animal Owner"];
SPListItem newOwner = itemList.Items.Add();
newOwner["Title"] = txtNewOwnerName.Text;
newOwner.Update();

int newID = newOwner.ID; //Here I reference the ID from the newly created list item
```